# Запись в MYSQL бита при котором меняется цвет svg на сайте

Tags: php, html, css, json

На страничке имеется изображение которое должно меняться относительно записей в MYSQL . На подобии если вбиваю на PHPMYADMIN единицу то на странице сайта svg рисунок будет красным гореть , если двойку записываю то зеленым .

Comment: Пишите программу на php, которая при обращении клиента читает инфу из БД, и отдает клиенту или уже готовую окрашенную SVG или например сами данные, а JS код на странице на основе них принимает решение как и что окрашивать

Comment: В том то и дело что здесь можно как то просто написать прогу. с помощью json передавать информацию ,а в php обрабатывать . Может есть вариант как сделать еще ?